# How to extend oneuiv3 in Xpages?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have tried to apply the new oneuiv3.0.2 styles to my application but failed.
My theme contains this:

```
<theme extends="oneuiv3.0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">
```

but no styles are applied. I can see in debugger that the css files are loaded.

If I change back to:

```
<theme extends="oneuiv2.1_orange" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">
```

it works as before.

If I change the Application theme in xsp properties to "oneuiv3.0.2 then my application gets the new "black" but then I can't get my quirks I have made in theme.

Please advice on how to use themes and override to oneuiv3!

Comment: @OliverBusse: It is part of Notes 9 and is deployed as an OSGi plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a simple theme with just the following:

```
<theme extends="oneuiv3.0.2" />
```

I have a very simple app that uses such a theme and it works. I can also switch between OneUI v1, OneUI v2 and OneUI v3: http://notesnet.dk/phlconsult/domino9.nsf

Comment: The difference is the declaration of namespace. Would that be the case why I'm not able to extend?

Comment: I could able to use oneui v3 theme, but all standard images are not loading.
Img tag source shows as follows: '/xsp/.ibmxspres/.oneuiv3/oneui/css/images/blank.gif'.
Anything I am missing here?

Comment: @PrashantArkal add a new question